# Using cardano-wallet with Plutip local cluster

Tags: wallet

I have to test integration Cardano with out services (written in c#, so I am totally noob in Haskel).

So I have built Plutip local cluster insing Nix and now  I can run Plutip local cluster in such a way:

```
/home/docker/plutip/result/bin/local-cluster \
  --wallets 3 \
  --wallet-dir /home/docker/cardano-data/wallets \
  --working-dir /home/docker/cardano-data/plutip \
  --ada 100000 \
  --utxos 5 \  
  --dump-info-json /home/docker/cardano-data/local-cluster-info.json
```

Then try running cardano-wallet:

```
cardano-wallet serve \
  --node-socket /home/docker/cardano-data/plutip/pool-1/node.socket \
  --mainnet \
  --tls-ca-cert cert2/ca-cert.pem \
  --tls-sv-cert cert2/server.crt \
  --tls-sv-key cert2/server.key \
  --listen-address 0.0.0.0 \
  --port 8090 \
  --database /home/docker/wallet-db
```

And here is the problem: when I use `--mainnet` because Plutip generates funds for the mainnet network, then wallet tries to synchronise for an extremely long time.

When I run wallet with the `--testnet /home/docker/cardano-data/plutip/genesis.byron.json` option, the sync is very fast, but wallet gives me an address in testnetwork, so I have no idea how to transfer funds between plutus addresses and wallet ones.

Any ideas how to get them to work together, either in mainnet, or in testnet address pool?